# update firebase entries on an interval

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, momentjs

I want to be able to update certain values in a firebase entry on a minute interval. I am not sure how to do this but have tried the following:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  database.ref().on('value',function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var item = childSnapshot.val();
        item.key = childSnapshot.key;
        database.ref(item.key).update({ item.trainTimeLeft: moment(item.trainFrequency).subtract(moment(moment(Date.now())).diff(item.trainTimeStamp,"minutes"),"minutes") });

    });
  });

},60000);
```

I am using moment.js for time differences (I am trying to make an updating train schedule). All of the entries are on the main branch of firebase.

Comment: i also want to add a condition to only do this if there are elements in firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` to trigger your function every X mile seconds you want.

Use `firebase.database.ref()` to access your database node you want to update.

Use `.update()` to update the database node value.

Use `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to get server time. Using client timestamp is not safe due different timezones.

With this you can write your function. It should look something like this

```
const serverTime = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
setInterval(() => {
  database.ref('myNode').once('value',(snapshot) => {
    const updatedDate = snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().storageTime ? snapshot.val().storageTime - serverTime : serverTime;
    snapshot.ref().update({ storageTime: updatedDate })
  });
}, 5000);
```

Consider this code just as an example, not a copy/paste solution.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "serverTime" not "servetTime" in const definition

Comment: Also, use ```.once``` instead of ```.on``` as you're adding an event listener every time this is called.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in polling the database, rather, tell it you want to listen for value (change) events.

From [Read and Write Data on the Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

> Important: The value event is called every time data is changed at the
>   specified database reference, including changes to children. To limit
>   the size of your snapshots, attach only at the lowest level needed for
>   watching changes. For example, attaching a listener to the root of
>   your database is not recommended. The following example demonstrates a
>   social blogging application retrieving the star count of a post from
>   the database:
>
> ```
> var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
> starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
>   updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
> });
> ```