# firebase retrieves data from different child because of child_added event

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database contains a list of users and each user has list containing his position and timestamp. 

  `runner
    |__1f9097c12fcfeac3259bd2be4a976933
    |__27305d166e57b5fdf9b96142c7d28ab1
       |__-L6R_u41IeEDy7rQ9udG
       |  |__timestamp
       |  |__position
    |__887527fea0ebca4c416e154e7bb8c95d
       |__-L6_KYQravVkxXNVK6V1
       |  |__timestamp
       |  |__position
       |__-L6_KekNbzzNrLY8G-IY
       |  |__timestamp
       |  |__position`

'887527fea0ebca4c416e154e7bb8c95d', '27305d166e57b5fdf9b96142c7d28ab1',.. etc are user's ID that is retrieved from mysql table. '-L6_KYQravVkxXNVK6V1', '-L6_KekNbzzNrLY8G-IY',.. etc are keys generated by firebase while pushing data.

I am querying for 1 particular user's position like this

`firebase.database().ref().child("runner").child(key).orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startdate).endAt(enddate).on("child_added", function(data) {...})`

While querying for user 1's positions, if child is added for user 2, I am getting user 2's positions though the `key` in above query still points to user 1.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49110805/edit) your question to include the relevant pieces of code.

Comment: key is the user's ID. Based on the selected user, I am getting his ID from mysql database and using that in firebase. @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting different user's details, because while selecting each user, I was attaching a `child_added` event listener. While changing the user , I was not removing the listener from previous user. Hence, when new child is added to different user, I was getting his details. The Solution is while changing to different user, remove listener from previous user.
`firebase.database().ref().child('runner/'+prev_key).off();`

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, then read the data once:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("runner").child(key).orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startdate).endAt(enddate).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var childData = child.val();
var timestamps=child.val().timestamp;
var position=child.val().position;
   )};
)};
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

Comment: But, I need to keep track of child added also, as I have to update the UI when new child is being added like live tracking of user, if he is using the app at that moment.

Comment: `on()` is used to retrieve maybe add to the database later using `set()` something like this `firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}` and then update the UI

Comment: Using `on( )` like this `firebase.database().ref().child("runner").child(key).orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startdate).endAt(enddate).on('value',function(snapshot) {...}) `  results in same error.. Whenever data is added to a user, his details are retrieved instead of the user details  that I am querying.

Comment: I meant once in the second comment

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't understand. Can you provide me with some example ?

Comment: I am using `push()` as I need to store all the data.  I have found a workaround for this. I am wrapping firebase data retrieval in setInterval function like this.. `setInterval(function(){ firebase.database().ref().child("runner").child(key).orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startdate).endAt(enddate).once('value').then(function(snapshot) { ...})  }, 30000)` . Is this approach correct ?

Comment: I am retrieving data every 30 sec.

Comment: @vaishali oh right I guess it will work since it is only reading data once every 30 seconds and not iterating through the whole parent node. If anything just increase time

Comment: I can't increase the time, as I am populating data every 30 sec from client side. Is there any better solution for this instead of using setInterval ?

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250375/update-firebase-entries-on-an-interval (and yes it seems only `setInterval()` is the solution for this situation)

Comment: thanks.. I have used `setInterval()`  in both the cases.. While populating the firebase database and while retrieving the data.