# Updating firebase database from an api automatically every time interval

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I'm making a react application with firebase realtime database.

I'm having a listener that checks for a certain key in the database and updates the state every time it detects a change which causes a re-render.

```
  const getTemperature = () => {
    var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('temperature');
    dbRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      setState(snapshot.val());
    });
  };
```

I want to make a self sustained script outside of the application that runs every 2 hours and updates the firebase data from an api. I can make a script and execute it manually every 2 hours but that looks tedious.

I know of Heroku but I have no idea how it's done.

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250375/update-firebase-entries-on-an-interval) because I want to update my data outside of my application. On a free server hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend having a look at Cloud Functions for Firebase, which allow you to run code (for example code that updates the database) on Google's servers. While Cloud Functions are likely going to only be available on Firebase's paid plan, they come with a generous free tier on that plan.

Comment: It's done with heroku [here](https://github.com/javieraviles/covidAPI), I think that's a bit easier to setup but couldn't find some good documentation.